# Using Random Forest classifiers post K-Means for Cluster Feature Importance

Tags: clustering, random-forest, k-means

I was wondering what the caveats were to the following process for describing clusters produced via K-Means with Random Forests:

> 1. Create clusters of data via K-Means
> 2. Train K random forests with a binary output where the label is 1 if that row belongs to the k'th cluster and 0 if it doesn't
> 3. Extract the top M important features from the K random forests pertaining to each cluster

As for now, I am using PCA to extract the principal eigenvector and then sorting the coefficients by absolute value to determine the top M important features. Let me know if you have any insight.

Comment: What for? K-means clusters are not very reliable. Run k-means multiple times, and you often get a completely different result.

Comment: Despite the initial centroids being randomly chosen, after a bunch of successive runs, the clusters are more or less the same every time for the data I am using.